# website authentication via url: mask url + ajax + php + htaccess?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is hard to explain, better with an example...

I have this valid url: `www.sitetoautenthicate.com/portal/index.php`.

To access this page, I want to mask the url to `www.sitetoautenthicate.com/portal/myportal/index.php` 
 where **myportal** has to be authenticated (exists in database) through an external API (ajax post).

I also want to forbid access to `www.sitetoautenthicate.com` and `www.sitetoautenthicate.com/portal/`

I think this can be done only with `.htaccess`

Comment: OK, but what is your question? What are you stuck with?

Comment: You want users to log in via AJAX and restrict www.sitetoautenthicate.com from who?

Comment: There are several websites `www.sitetoautenthicate.com` and, to authenticate via API, it is necessary to request with username, password and name of the portal itself (myportal), in this case... how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `I also want to forbid access to www.sitetoautenthicate.com and www.sitetoautenthicate.com/portal/`

Try this rule in in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sitetoautenthicate\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(portal)?/?$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the easy part... ;)